# How to print the contents of the head of the array and delete it

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, queue, function-pointers

Im trying to create a queue so i need the array to be stored in reverse so that the last input can be the head of the array so i can add stuff and delete previous inputs with the head leaving first (fifo). I made the function head_find to count the pointer till last spot and then delete it and shift over. contents

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//struct node *head;
//struct node *size;
int head;

void reverse_array(int*, int);

int main(){
int x,i,c,length;
char collect;
int rear = -1;
int front = -1;
int *size = NULL;

START:while(1){
printf("Enter operation \n");
scanf("%c",&collect);


 switch(collect) {
      case 'C' :
         printf("create queue\n");
                printf("enter size of queue \n");
                scanf("%d",&x);
                if(x <=0){
                printf("Numbers Entered must be non Zero postive Numbers \n");
                }
                else
                printf("Numbers is good \n");   
                goto START;   // leave case

         break;
      case 'I' :
          printf("write vaules\n");
          if (front == -1)
            //  int *size =calloc(x,sizeof(int));           //make size of array
             size = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*x);    
                    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
                    scanf("%d",(size+i));   
                //  scanf("%d",&(size[i]));     // scan vaules to address
                    }
                    /*
                    for(i=x-1;d=0;i>=0;i--;d++)
                        int *size2 =calloc(x,sizeof(int));
                        &(size[d]))=&(size[i]); 
                    for (c = 0; c < x; c++)
                         printf("%d\n", &(size[c]);
                    */  
          break;
      case 'R' :
         printf("Read head of queue\n");
                /* if (front == - 1)
        printf("Queue is empty \n");
         */
            head =head_find(&size);
            printf("head is %d \n",head);




         break;
      case 'P' :
         printf("print contents=\n");

            if (x==0){     // not working as a check
                printf("queue is empty\n");
            }
            else
                reverse_array(size,x);
             for ( i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
                printf("size[%d]= %d\n", i,*(size+i));

                free(size); 



         break;
      case 'L' :
         printf("get length of queue\n");
            length=point_ln(size);
            printf("Length is %d \n",length);

         break;
      case 'M' :
         printf("Modify length\n");
         break;
      default:
         printf("letter must be in caps \n");
   }

}




return 0;
}

int head_find(int *c){
    int begin =0;
while(*c != '\0'){
    begin --;
    c++;



}
    return &c;



}

int point_ln(int *p){
    int start =0;
while (*p != '\0') {
      start++;
      p++;
   }
   return start;

}


void reverse_array(int *size,int x){
    int i,d;
    int *rev =calloc(x,sizeof(int));

    if( rev == NULL )
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   for ( i = x - 1, d = 0; i >= 0; i--, d++ )
      *(rev+d) = *(size+i);

   for ( i = 0 ; i< x ; i++)
      *(size+i) = *(rev+i);

   free(rev);

}
```

Comment: Your code defines `reverse_array()` twice. Does this compile? If yes you aren't using a C compiler.

Comment: Also please indent your code properly. As it stand it's (too?) difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realise that `size` is a local variable inside your loop?  The only time it is initialised is in `case 'I'`.  Then you leak it and next time around the loop you'll have an uninitialised value for `case 'P'`.

Move the definition *outside of your loop*:

```
int *size = NULL;
while(1) {
    // ...
}
```

Your compiler should have warned you about defining a variable inside a switch statement.  It can lead to confusion exactly like you are experiencing.

You also have a problem with the call to `reverse_array`.  You are passing `&size[i]` where `i` is most likely equal to `x` from a previous loop.  Just pass `size`:

```
reverse_array( size, x );
```

However, I don't see why you need to reverse the array in order to print it in reverse.  I also don't see why you copy the entire array to reverse it, when all you need is one variable for swapping.

Comment: well i need to capture the head of the array i figured if i reverse it I'll know where it is. I also fixed  that function . Do you have any ideas how to capture the head of the array without using link list??